# What is a word that means "does not collapse?"

Tags: single-word-requests

For example:

> Although there was an earthquake, my house **did not collapse**.
>
> Although there was an earthquake, my house **[positive action verb]**.

I've considered "withstood," but it sounds strange to me on its own: "My house withstood the earthquake" is fine, but "Although there was an earthquake, my house withstood" sounds kind of clunky without an object.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best word I can think of for that particular situation is *endured*. If you're willing to go with a phrase instead, you can use something like *stood strong*.

Answer (score 1):

My house was **untouched**, **unaffected**, **impervious**

A positive action verb might be: **survived** [unscathed].